# Need help to extract data pattern from a list as shown below

Tags: regex, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have data example as shown below and i want to extract data which has key/value pattern like:

```
'Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256', 'Not Before: Jul 23 00:00:00 2018 GMT', 'Not After : Jul 19 00:00:00 2033 GMT, 'Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKeyid', Public-Key: (256 bit)'
```

The example:

```
['Certificate:', 'Data:', 'Version: 3 (0x2)', 'Serial Number:', 'b9:d9:f5:38:f8:42:6a:f9', 'Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256', 'Issuer: C=US, ST=NC, L=Raleigh, O=Eaton Corporation, OU=Electrical Division, CN=PowerXpert-02-00-34-56-63-01', 'Validity', 'Not Before: Jul 23 00:00:00 2018 GMT', 'Not After : Jul 19 00:00:00 2033 GMT', 'Subject: C=US, ST=NC, L=Raleigh, O=Eaton Corporation, OU=Electrical Division, CN=PowerXpert-02-00-34-56-63-01', 'Subject Public Key Info:', 'Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey', 'Public-Key: (256 bit)', 'pub:', '04:bf:72:4b:01:8b:5c:46:98:96:a6:d6:06:7b:d8:', '73:50:2f:47:85:60:f0:38:25:79:3d:96:be:20:3b:', '3f:39:c8:58:62:e9:d7:b6:f8:3a:6b:24:50:e1:5c:', '78:ce:5e:28:f2:60:3a:b6:cc:43:0e:0b:2b:d6:03:', '51:76:21:a4:78', 'ASN1 OID: prime256v1', 'NIST CURVE: P-256', 'X509v3 extensions:', 'X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:', '6A:E0:28:A7:17:2B:65:01:FD:31:48:5C:68:24:94:4B:42:49:76:58', 'X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical', 'CA:TRUE', 'X509v3 Key Usage: critical', 'Digital Signature, Certificate Sign, CRL Sign', 'X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:', 'DNS:PXG900-56-63-01', 'Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256', '30:45:02:20:43:33:58:ce:ef:f7:fd:a8:60:21:15:a3:2b:35:', '8c:1f:13:a0:1e:77:05:6f:1a:bb:a0:b6:fe:f3:ea:7b:6d:31:', '02:21:00:cf:db:9a:d1:6b:88:ae:fb:d5:5c:5a:db:0a:a0:eb:', 'a9:c9:4a:52:d0:57:18:9c:58:1b:67:42:47:c5:ec:bf:b0', '', '']
```

Using below regex but not getting the desired result

```
regex = re.compile(r'''
[\S]+:                # a key (any word followed by a colon)
(?:
\s                    # then a space in between
(?!\S+:)\S+           # then a value (any word not followed by a colon)
)+                    # match multiple values if present
''', re.VERBOSE)

matches = regex.findall(str(lines))
print(matches)
```

Comment: `lines`  is that a list?

Comment: yes lines is a list of data

Comment: What is the desired result? Please format the question.

Comment: From the list shown, i want the key/value pattern of data like ('Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256', 'Not Before: Jul 23 00:00:00 2018 GMT', 'Not After : Jul 19 00:00:00 2033 GMT')

Comment: you can turn it into a dictionary and use it the way you want: `dictionary =  eval(re.sub(r"\s*'?([^,']+?)\s*:\s*([^,']+)[',]*",r"'\1':'\2',",a).join('{}'))` where `a` is the string you gave. Or rather, you can just split it `a.split(",")` to produce the answer given below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether I fully understand. But couldn't you just go:

```
extracted = []
for item in lines:
    if len(item.split(": ")) == 2: # It has 2 items
        extracted.append(item)
```

This will extract every item which has "stuff" on either side of a ": ". 
I hope this helps.

Comment: it is perfect for all kind of data!

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following regular expression:

`(?='[A-Za-z]+[\s-][A-Z][a-z]+\s?:?)'[^']+:[^']+'`

- `(?=` Positive lookahead. Assert that what follows is:

  - `'[A-Za-z]+`, a apostrophe `'` character, followed by alphabetic characters.
  - `[\s-]` a whitespace or dash `-`.
  - `[A-Za-z]+` alphabetic characters.
  - `\s?` optional whitespace.
  - `:?\s` optional colon `:` followed by whitespace.
- `)` close lookahead.
- `'[^']+` Matches a apostrophe  `'` character, anything that is not a apostrophe  `'` character.
- `:` Match a colon.
- `[^']+'` Matches anything that is not a apostrophe `'` character, followed by apostrophe `'`.

You can test the regex live [here](https://regex101.com/r/KjwpEH/4).

---

Python snippet:

```
import re
lines = ['Certificate:', 'Data:', 'Version: 3 (0x2)', 'Serial Number:', 'b9:d9:f5:38:f8:42:6a:f9', 'Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256', 'Issuer: C=US, ST=NC, L=Raleigh, O=Eaton Corporation, OU=Electrical Division, CN=PowerXpert-02-00-34-56-63-01', 'Validity', 'Not Before: Jul 23 00:00:00 2018 GMT', 'Not After : Jul 19 00:00:00 2033 GMT','Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey',
'Public-Key: (256 bit)']
matches = re.findall(r"(?='[A-Za-z]+[\s-][A-Z][a-z]+\s?:?)'[^']+:[^']+'",str(lines))
for match in matches:
    print (match)
```

Output:

```
'Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256'
'Not Before: Jul 23 00:00:00 2018 GMT'
'Not After : Jul 19 00:00:00 2033 GMT'
'Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey'
'Public-Key: (256 bit)'
'Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256'
```

Comment: Thanks, that is working but what if we have some more data like below which are also to be extracted along with previous one?
'Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey', 'Public-Key: (256 bit)'

Comment: @coding_learner Please add all additional information to the original question.

Comment: Is this not just `lines.split(",")`?

Comment: @Onyambu No. If you check the open post, he does not want every pair of key : value but rather only specific entries.

Comment: I see lines is a list.. sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regular expression to extract key value pair.

```
([a-zA-Z0-9 ]*:[a-zA-Z0-9\- :]*)
```

[Demo Link](https://www.regextester.com/index.php?fam=104222)

Comment: using your suggestion, it is extracting all the keys values but including keys which has value as space as well.
Example:
pub:
anything:

Comment: i do not want that key which has not value, i mean to say ignore value as a spce

Comment: I did not get it. You have 3 key value pairs. this regex finds all the key value pairs, in your case it its 3, you can have that as a list and use simple regex to separate key value pairs in a loop.

Comment: @coding_learner your instructions are not clear. If you wanted every key value pair why is `Version: 3 (0x2)` not in the desired output? My understanding was that only certain patterns were to be matched, which is what my regular expression does.

Comment: @nikesh: what output i got using your regex is basically can be gotten from a simple for loop as well...
for match in lines:print(match)
exactly same output then what is use of regex here?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness Your answer has solved 80% of my query but would be 100% if did not get below type of elements while using your pattern...
'Subject Public Key Info:'

Comment: @coding_learner can you confirm that `(?='[A-Za-z]+[\s-][A-Z][a-z]+\s?:?)'[^']+:[^']+'` [here](https://regex101.com/r/KjwpEH/4) matches all the desired patterns? If so I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 re.findall("'[A-Z][^':]+:[^',:]+(?:\d{2}:){0,3}[^',:]+'(?=,)",str(lines))
Out[139]: 
["'Version: 3 (0x2)'",
 "'Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256'",
 "'Not Before: Jul 23 00:00:00 2018 GMT'",
 "'Not After : Jul 19 00:00:00 2033 GMT'",
 "'Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey'",
 "'Public-Key: (256 bit)'",
 "'ASN1 OID: prime256v1'",
 "'NIST CURVE: P-256'",
 "'X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical'",
 "'CA:TRUE'",
 "'X509v3 Key Usage: critical'",
 "'DNS:PXG900-56-63-01'",
 "'Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256'"]
```

Comment: `'Version: 3 (0x2)`,`b9:d9`, `'Issuer: C=US` are not in the desired output.

Comment: This is also missing `Public-Key: (256 bit)`, which is included in the desired result

Comment: @UnbearableLightness I have edited the answer. You can remove your downvote now. Also `Version: 3 (0x2)` should be there since it has a key-value pattern. The result printed was an example of what OP was looking for.

Comment: My understanding was that he only wanted specific entries. Otherwise he should have just stated *I want every key value pair* ...

Comment: @UnbearableLightness OP stated clearly that they want key-value. Try running the accepted solution and you will see what I am saying